# Android, to save into internal Storage

Tags: android, storage, internal

I'm testing on my divice, I get FALSE in this line

```
Boolean isSDPresent = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
```

So, I don't have external storage in my device, correct?, how can i save a image on my internal storage? if I put this line...

```
FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

The class complete

```
public class ImageStorage {

public static String saveFile(Bitmap bitmap, String filename) {




    try {
        FileOutputStream out = context.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

   }


public static File getImage(String imagename) {

    File mediaImage = null;
    try {
        String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File myDir = new File(root);
        if (!myDir.exists())
            return null;

        mediaImage = new File(myDir.getPath() + "/images/"+imagename);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return mediaImage;
}

public static boolean checkifImageExists(String imagename)
{
    Bitmap b = null ;
    File file = ImageStorage.getImage("/"+imagename+".jpg");
    String path = file.getAbsolutePath();

    if (path != null)
        b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path); 

    if(b == null ||  b.equals(""))
    {
        return false ;
    }
    return true ;
}
```

}

The word "context" it's marked as "cannot be resolved". I have spent one week with this issue, please help me

Comment: Show us the rest of the code! Apparently you did not define context before, but without any code we can't help you.

Comment: OKs Jeffrey, I put the method

Comment: Where does this code live, is it an Activity? Please post a bit more context :)

Comment: No, it not an Activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because this class does not by default has access to a `Context`, you will need to pass it in the method like this (see how I added the `Context` parameter):

```
public static String saveFile(Context context, Bitmap bitmap, String filename) {}
```

So when you call it, you will need to pass some kind of context. If you call it from an `Activity`, you can simply use `this`.

Comment: And if not call from Activity ? I call it from another generic class

Comment: In that case you will have to pass a `Context` to that class as well, just like we did in the answer above; add it as a parameter.

Comment: I call from public class GetImages extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>

Comment: If the AsyncTask is a subclass in an Activity, you can call `ActivityName.this`, where ActivityName is the name of the activity. If the AsyncTask is not in an Activity, then you will need to pass the context to the AsyncTask in the constructor (so add the Context parameter again, just like in the answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String saveFile(Bitmap bitmap, String filename) {
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = context.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The reason that your code doesn't work: `context` cannot be resolved. Within the code, there's nothing called `context`. You have to add it as parameter (your `Activity` extends `Context`, so you can pass that as parameter, and call this in your `Activity`: `saveFile(this, mbitmap, mfilename)`

```
public static String saveFile(Context context, Bitmap bitmap, String filename)...
```

That, or you have to remove `static`, and make the method a member of your `Activity` class, and change `context` into `this` (or remove it). See below.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    //your activity members

    public String saveFile(Bitmap bitmap, String filename) {
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = this.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

if the method is called from an inner `AsyncTask` class, call `MyActivity.this.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)`

Comment: Oks, I removed static, now openFileOutput is undefined

Comment: Because you didn't declare your method in an `Activity`, but somewhere else. Pass it as a parameter.

Comment: I call it from a extends AsyncTask class